# New to hosting! How do I keep my domain name but leave wordpress.com and host a website using my own html/css files?

Tags: html, wordpress, hosting

I created a history blog on wordpress.com a little while back and used one of the default themes. I was satisfied with the design but wanted to put my web design skills to the test; so I opened Visual Studio and photoshop and spent about a month on making something I'm pretty proud of.

The problem is that I purchased my domain from wordpress.com and (not knowing a lot about hosting) I couldn't find a way to use my code on their site.

I soon found out I can't do that. Not with my own html files anyway. I would have to re-write my entire design.

What I need help with due to my limited knowledge of hosting is this:

How can I leave wordpress.com and keep my domain name? I paid for a year.

Once I leave wordpress, where can I find a place to host my website online by uploading my index.html and all additional files?

I haven't done ANY website hosting since the days of geocities!

Comment: There's an official guide for exactly this kind of situation: https://move.wordpress.com/

Comment: Also, you'll want to reach out to WordPress.com's support team and ask them about using your domain elsewhere as that's not explained in their guide.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the domain situation but you can host you're website files and deploy it on Netlify. They have an incredibly generous free tier thats more than enough!
https://netlify.com